# Data class primary constructor must have only property (val / var) parameters

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin

I am converting my Json into data object class:

The JSON comes in this format:

```
entry":[
{
 "im:name": {"label":"Growin' Up"}
 .... 
}
```

So in my data class I have:

```
data class Entry(
val im:name: ImName
)
```

But I am having an arror:

```
Data class primary constructor must have only property (val / var) parameters
```

I cant change the JSON returned

Comment: _im:name_ is not a valid name in Kotlin. Use _imName_ or backticks _\`im:name\`_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`im:name` is an invalid variable name in kotlin, if you are using Moshi library for conversion you can use `@Json` annoation so your you data class should looks like this:

```
import com.squareup.moshi.Json

data class Entry(
    @Json(name = "im:name")
    val imName: ImName
)
```

If you are using Gson library, you can use `@SerializedName` annotation which is simular to `@Json` so your data class should looks like this:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class Entry(
    @SerializedName("im:name")
    val imName: ImName
)
```

Comment: Sadly, I am using GSON :(

Comment: I added what you can use for Gson